# Spark Sql ODBC client

Tags: c#, apache-spark, thrift

Following the instructions on Apache Spark document(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-distributed-sql-engine.html), I was able to run the Thrift JDBC/ODBC server on local machine with the port 10000 and test JDBC with beeline:

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

However, I didn't find any resource to connect the Thrift server via ODBC in C# code.
Is there any sample code for doing that?

Thanks!